# Sharepoint/One Drive "Free up space"

Tags: windows, onedrive, ms-dos, sharepoint

I use sharepoint to host files on the cloud, with a shortcut added to OneDrive so we can browse the files through windows explorer.

We have a lot of automation, which pulls files locally and processes them and then saves the results back to sharepoint.

I would like to automatically remove those files from the **local device only**, ideally via a DOS command.

I know you can interactively do it by selecting the "Free up space" from the right click menu as shown in the image below.

Is it possible to automate this via a dos command?

[image: Right click options]

Answer (score 1):

Storage Sense in Windows settings might be a good option, which is able to delete files on a regular basis.
[image]

Comment: This is a good overall solution - I would like to be able to target specific folders/paths if possible?